# Android integrating PGP into a project

Tags: java, android, encryption, bouncycastle, pgp

I'm pretty familiar with PGP, and the way it works.  I'd like to include some functionality in a project, but so far my research has left my head spinning.  What I'd like to do is create a public key with a defined private pass phrase.  From there, I'd share the public key with someone where they can then encrypt a message using the key and return it to me where I can decrypt. I envision the code looking something like this.

To generate my private pgp key:

```
PGPKey key = new PGPKey();
key.setPassPhrase("MySecretPassword!!!1");
key.generateRandomSharedKey();
key.build();
```

To encrypt I'd give my shared key to a friend:

```
String encryptedText = PGPTools.Encrypt("Text to encrypt", getSharedKey());
```

To decrypt the encrypted string after being sent back to me:

```
String decryptedText = PGPTools.Decrypt(encryptedText, key, "MySecretPassword!!!1")
```

Obviously I know I'm skipping out on a ton of details.  Through my research I've seen references to libraries like Bouncy Castle and Spongy Castle.  Any help would be hugely appreciated!

Comment: Looks good, what trouble are you having.

Comment: As bad as it sounds, I guess I'm looking for exact code more or less.  Every code example I'm finding online is different in one way or another or excluding important parts all together.

Comment: Welcome to the world of OSS <bg>

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I want to post my solution because A. it was extremely difficult to get this working, and B. If any crypto pro's want to audit my code I'd be eternally grateful.

I included the 4 following libraries:

```
compile 'com.madgag.spongycastle:core:1.50.0.0'
compile 'com.madgag.spongycastle:pg:1.50.0.0'
compile 'com.madgag.spongycastle:pkix:1.50.0.0'
compile 'com.madgag.spongycastle:prov:1.50.0.0'
```

Bouncy Castle needs to be added as a security provider.  I included this code in a class that initializes some other objects when the app loads.

```
static {
    Security.addProvider(new BouncyCastleProvider());
}
```

Here's the utils class I created that really contains the nuts and bolts.  Edited slightly:

```
import com.example.Device;

import org.spongycastle.bcpg.ArmoredInputStream;
import org.spongycastle.bcpg.ArmoredOutputStream;
import org.spongycastle.bcpg.HashAlgorithmTags;
import org.spongycastle.bcpg.SymmetricKeyAlgorithmTags;
import org.spongycastle.bcpg.sig.Features;
import org.spongycastle.bcpg.sig.KeyFlags;
import org.spongycastle.crypto.generators.RSAKeyPairGenerator;
import org.spongycastle.crypto.params.RSAKeyGenerationParameters;
import org.spongycastle.openpgp.PGPCompressedData;
import org.spongycastle.openpgp.PGPCompressedDataGenerator;
import org.spongycastle.openpgp.PGPEncryptedData;
import org.spongycastle.openpgp.PGPEncryptedDataGenerator;
import org.spongycastle.openpgp.PGPEncryptedDataList;
import org.spongycastle.openpgp.PGPException;
import org.spongycastle.openpgp.PGPKeyPair;
import org.spongycastle.openpgp.PGPKeyRingGenerator;
import org.spongycastle.openpgp.PGPLiteralData;
import org.spongycastle.openpgp.PGPLiteralDataGenerator;
import org.spongycastle.openpgp.PGPObjectFactory;
import org.spongycastle.openpgp.PGPPrivateKey;
import org.spongycastle.openpgp.PGPPublicKey;
import org.spongycastle.openpgp.PGPPublicKeyEncryptedData;
import org.spongycastle.openpgp.PGPPublicKeyRing;
import org.spongycastle.openpgp.PGPSecretKey;
import org.spongycastle.openpgp.PGPSecretKeyRing;
import org.spongycastle.openpgp.PGPSignature;
import org.spongycastle.openpgp.PGPSignatureSubpacketGenerator;
import org.spongycastle.openpgp.PGPUtil;
import org.spongycastle.openpgp.operator.PBESecretKeyDecryptor;
import org.spongycastle.openpgp.operator.PBESecretKeyEncryptor;
import org.spongycastle.openpgp.operator.PGPDigestCalculator;
import org.spongycastle.openpgp.operator.bc.BcPBESecretKeyDecryptorBuilder;
import org.spongycastle.openpgp.operator.bc.BcPBESecretKeyEncryptorBuilder;
import org.spongycastle.openpgp.operator.bc.BcPGPContentSignerBuilder;
import org.spongycastle.openpgp.operator.bc.BcPGPDigestCalculatorProvider;
import org.spongycastle.openpgp.operator.bc.BcPGPKeyPair;
import org.spongycastle.openpgp.operator.bc.BcPublicKeyDataDecryptorFactory;
import org.spongycastle.openpgp.operator.jcajce.JcePGPDataEncryptorBuilder;
import org.spongycastle.openpgp.operator.jcajce.JcePublicKeyKeyEncryptionMethodGenerator;

import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;
import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.math.BigInteger;
import java.nio.charset.Charset;
import java.security.SecureRandom;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.Iterator;

public class PgpUtils {
    private static final String PROVIDER = "SC";
    private static final String KEY_RING_ID = "asdf@asdf.com";

    public static String decrypt(String encryptedText, String password) throws Exception {
        byte[] encrypted = encryptedText.getBytes();
        InputStream in = new ByteArrayInputStream(encrypted);
        in = PGPUtil.getDecoderStream(in);
        PGPObjectFactory pgpF = new PGPObjectFactory(in);
        PGPEncryptedDataList enc;
        Object o = pgpF.nextObject();
        if (o instanceof PGPEncryptedDataList) {
            enc = (PGPEncryptedDataList) o;
        } else {
            enc = (PGPEncryptedDataList) pgpF.nextObject();
        }
        PGPPrivateKey sKey = null;
        PGPPublicKeyEncryptedData pbe = null;
        while (sKey == null && enc.getEncryptedDataObjects().hasNext()) {
            pbe = (PGPPublicKeyEncryptedData)enc.getEncryptedDataObjects().next();
            sKey = getPrivateKey(getPGPSecretKeyRing(), pbe.getKeyID(), password.toCharArray());
        }
        if (pbe != null) {
            InputStream clear = pbe.getDataStream(new BcPublicKeyDataDecryptorFactory(sKey));
            PGPObjectFactory pgpFact = new PGPObjectFactory(clear);
            PGPCompressedData cData = (PGPCompressedData) pgpFact.nextObject();
            pgpFact = new PGPObjectFactory(cData.getDataStream());
            PGPLiteralData ld = (PGPLiteralData) pgpFact.nextObject();
            InputStream unc = ld.getInputStream();
            ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            int ch;
            while ((ch = unc.read()) >= 0) {
                out.write(ch);
            }
            byte[] returnBytes = out.toByteArray();
            out.close();
            return new String(returnBytes);
        }
        return null;
    }

    private static PGPPublicKey getPublicKey(PGPPublicKeyRing publicKeyRing) {
        Iterator<?> kIt = publicKeyRing.getPublicKeys();
        while (kIt.hasNext()) {
            PGPPublicKey k = (PGPPublicKey) kIt.next();
            if (k.isEncryptionKey()) {
                return k;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

    private static PGPPrivateKey getPrivateKey(PGPSecretKeyRing keyRing, long keyID, char[] pass) throws PGPException {
        PGPSecretKey secretKey = keyRing.getSecretKey(keyID);
        PBESecretKeyDecryptor decryptor = new BcPBESecretKeyDecryptorBuilder(new BcPGPDigestCalculatorProvider()).build(pass);
        return secretKey.extractPrivateKey(decryptor);
    }

    public static String encrypt(String msgText) throws IOException, PGPException {
        byte[] clearData = msgText.getBytes();
        PGPPublicKey encKey = getPublicKey(getPGPPublicKeyRing());
        ByteArrayOutputStream encOut = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        OutputStream out = new ArmoredOutputStream(encOut);
        ByteArrayOutputStream bOut = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        PGPCompressedDataGenerator comData = new PGPCompressedDataGenerator(PGPCompressedDataGenerator.ZIP);
        OutputStream cos = comData.open(bOut);
        PGPLiteralDataGenerator lData = new PGPLiteralDataGenerator();
        OutputStream pOut = lData.open(cos, PGPLiteralData.BINARY, PGPLiteralData.CONSOLE, clearData.length, new Date());
        pOut.write(clearData);
        lData.close();
        comData.close();
        PGPEncryptedDataGenerator encGen =
                new PGPEncryptedDataGenerator(
                        new JcePGPDataEncryptorBuilder(PGPEncryptedData.AES_256).setWithIntegrityPacket(true).setSecureRandom(
                                new SecureRandom()).setProvider(PROVIDER));
        if (encKey != null) {
            encGen.addMethod(new JcePublicKeyKeyEncryptionMethodGenerator(encKey).setProvider(PROVIDER));
            byte[] bytes = bOut.toByteArray();
            OutputStream cOut = encGen.open(out, bytes.length);
            cOut.write(bytes);
            cOut.close();
        }
        out.close();
        return new String(encOut.toByteArray());
    }

    public final static PGPKeyRingGenerator generateKeyRingGenerator (char[] pass) throws PGPException{
        RSAKeyPairGenerator kpg = new RSAKeyPairGenerator();
        kpg.init(new RSAKeyGenerationParameters(BigInteger.valueOf(0x10001), new SecureRandom(), 2048, 12));
        PGPKeyPair rsakp_sign = new BcPGPKeyPair(PGPPublicKey.RSA_SIGN, kpg.generateKeyPair(), new Date());
        PGPKeyPair rsakp_enc = new BcPGPKeyPair(PGPPublicKey.RSA_ENCRYPT, kpg.generateKeyPair(), new Date());
        PGPSignatureSubpacketGenerator signhashgen = new PGPSignatureSubpacketGenerator();
        signhashgen.setKeyFlags(false, KeyFlags.SIGN_DATA|KeyFlags.CERTIFY_OTHER|KeyFlags.SHARED);
        signhashgen.setPreferredSymmetricAlgorithms(false, new int[]{SymmetricKeyAlgorithmTags.AES_256, SymmetricKeyAlgorithmTags.AES_192, SymmetricKeyAlgorithmTags.AES_128});
        signhashgen.setPreferredHashAlgorithms(false, new int[]{HashAlgorithmTags.SHA256, HashAlgorithmTags.SHA1, HashAlgorithmTags.SHA384, HashAlgorithmTags.SHA512, HashAlgorithmTags.SHA224});
        signhashgen.setFeature(false, Features.FEATURE_MODIFICATION_DETECTION);
        PGPSignatureSubpacketGenerator enchashgen = new PGPSignatureSubpacketGenerator();
        enchashgen.setKeyFlags(false, KeyFlags.ENCRYPT_COMMS | KeyFlags.ENCRYPT_STORAGE);
        PGPDigestCalculator sha1Calc = new BcPGPDigestCalculatorProvider().get(HashAlgorithmTags.SHA1);
        PGPDigestCalculator sha256Calc = new BcPGPDigestCalculatorProvider().get(HashAlgorithmTags.SHA256);
        PBESecretKeyEncryptor pske = (new BcPBESecretKeyEncryptorBuilder(PGPEncryptedData.AES_256, sha256Calc, 0xc0)).build(pass);
        PGPKeyRingGenerator keyRingGen = new PGPKeyRingGenerator (PGPSignature.POSITIVE_CERTIFICATION, rsakp_sign,
                KEY_RING_ID, sha1Calc, signhashgen.generate(), null, new BcPGPContentSignerBuilder(rsakp_sign.getPublicKey().getAlgorithm(),
                HashAlgorithmTags.SHA1), pske);
        keyRingGen.addSubKey(rsakp_enc, enchashgen.generate(), null);
        return keyRingGen;
    }

    private static PGPPublicKeyRing getPGPPublicKeyRing() throws IOException {
        ArmoredInputStream ais = new ArmoredInputStream(new ByteArrayInputStream(Device.getDevice().getPgpPublicKey().getBytes()));
        return (PGPPublicKeyRing) new PGPObjectFactory(ais).nextObject();
    }

    private static PGPSecretKeyRing getPGPSecretKeyRing() throws IOException {
        ArmoredInputStream ais = new ArmoredInputStream(new ByteArrayInputStream(Device.getDevice().getPgpSecretKey().getBytes()));
        return (PGPSecretKeyRing) new PGPObjectFactory(ais).nextObject();
    }

    public final static String genPGPPublicKey (PGPKeyRingGenerator krgen) throws IOException {
        ByteArrayOutputStream baosPkr = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        PGPPublicKeyRing pkr = krgen.generatePublicKeyRing();
        ArmoredOutputStream armoredStreamPkr = new ArmoredOutputStream(baosPkr);
        pkr.encode(armoredStreamPkr);
        armoredStreamPkr.close();
        return new String(baosPkr.toByteArray(), Charset.defaultCharset());
    }

    public final static String genPGPPrivKey (PGPKeyRingGenerator krgen) throws IOException {
        ByteArrayOutputStream baosPriv = new ByteArrayOutputStream ();
        PGPSecretKeyRing skr = krgen.generateSecretKeyRing();
        ArmoredOutputStream armoredStreamPriv = new ArmoredOutputStream(baosPriv);
        skr.encode(armoredStreamPriv);
        armoredStreamPriv.close();
        return new String(baosPriv.toByteArray(), Charset.defaultCharset());
    }
}
```

Here is how I create the private and public keys:

```
final PGPKeyRingGenerator krgen = PgpUtils.generateKeyRingGenerator("password".toCharArray());
String pgpPublicKey = PgpUtils.genPGPPublicKey(krgen);
String pgpSecretKey = PgpUtils.genPGPPrivKey(krgen);
```

And finally encrypting and decrypting using your own public key:

```
String encrypted = PgpUtils.encrypt("message text");
String decrypted = PgpUtils.decrypt(encrypted, "Password");
```

Comment: Thanks it worked. Just had to do minor modification for decripting as the encrypted message not not getting compressed at server end.

Comment: Any idea how to implement similar for iOS which is open source?

Comment: i've created an android library based on joey_g216's solution: https://github.com/kibotu/Android-PGP

Answer (score 2):

I don't have enough rep to comment on joey_g216 excellent answer above. Initially it worked for me, but then failed on decrypting various files. This is because the structure of a PGPObject can change.

To get decryption to work I had to adjust:

```
public static String decrypt(String encryptedText, String password) throws Exception {
```

to include:

```
// Could be
// signature + compressed -> data
// signature + data
// data
// compressed -> data

Object z = pgpFact.nextObject();
while (!(z instanceof PGPLiteralData))
{

    if (z instanceof PGPCompressedData) {
        PGPCompressedData cData = (PGPCompressedData) z;
        pgpFact = new PGPObjectFactory(cData.getDataStream(), bcKeyFingerprintCalculator);
    }

    if (z instanceof PGPOnePassSignatureList) {
        // ignore for now!
    }

    z = pgpFact.nextObject();

}
PGPLiteralData ld = (PGPLiteralData) z;
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you want to generate a public key pair using BouncyCastle?

This one asks how to do it without a password, but you can take a look how to do it with a password too:
[How to generate OpenPGP KeyPair without passphrase using BouncyCastle?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5607698/how-to-generate-openpgp-keypair-without-passphrase-using-bouncycastle)

Comment: Yeah, that is very close.  Finding code examples of how to define the password has been next to impossible for me.

Comment: @JoeGoble Glad to be of help!

Comment: BC is massive library and integrating into your app should be a last resort.